# How to count consecutive weeks in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with a list of string dates, and the length of each list:

```
data = [['a', ['8/5/2021'], 1], ['b', ['12/21/2021', '12/28/2021'], 2], ['c', ['8/10/2021',  '8/27/2021', '9/3/2021', '9/10/2021', '9/17/2021'], 5], ['d', ['8/23/2021', '9/23/2021', '10/23/2021'], 3], ['e', ['8/10/2021',  '9/27/2021', '10/3/2021', '11/10/2021', '11/17/2021', '12/27/2021'], 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Dates', 'Total Weeks'])
```

I want to count the number of consecutive weeks in each list, and it'll be "one period". No matter how long it'll be, it'll be one period. One week on its own would also be considered "one period". I want to append this to a new column of the dataframe.

Finally, I'll like to count only the "periods" that are at least 2 weeks long or more. This would be appended to the dataframe as a new column. The end result should look like this:

[image]

I was thinking of using datetime.timedelta and groupby but can't seem to figure it out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @TCMolenaar Hello! Periods = 3 is because there are 3 different "periods" (which can be 1 week/instance long). >=2 equals 0 because I'm only looking for the periods that are 2 weeks/instances long for that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC: I made a second dataframe (`df_long`) to do the calculations using `df.explode()`.

By using `df.groupby('Name')` I created new columns. `non_consec_weeks` is a boolean column which checks if the row is a new period (week). If false, it is part of week of another row within the group. `consec_weeks` is the negation of the column `non_consec_weeks`. And finally `week_periods` is similar to `consec_weeks` but sets only a single `True` value for every group of consecutive weeks.

```
df_long = df.explode('Dates').reset_index(drop=True)
df_long['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df_long.Dates) #, format="%d/%m/%Y")

df_long['non_consec_weeks'] = ~df_long.groupby('Name').Dates.diff().dt.days.le(7)
df_long['consec_weeks'] = df_long.groupby('Name').Dates.diff().dt.days.le(7)
df_long['week_periods'] = df_long['consec_weeks'] & ~(df_long['consec_weeks'] & (df_long.groupby('Name').consec_weeks.shift() == df_long.consec_weeks))

df['Periods'] = df_long.groupby('Name').non_consec_weeks.sum().values
df['>=2'] = df_long.groupby('Name').week_periods.sum().values
```

Output:

```
  Name                                              Dates  ...  Periods  >=2
0    a                                         [8/5/2021]  ...        1    0
1    b                           [12/21/2021, 12/28/2021]  ...        1    1
2    c  [8/10/2021, 8/27/2021, 9/3/2021, 9/10/2021, 9/...  ...        2    1
3    d                 [8/23/2021, 9/23/2021, 10/23/2021]  ...        3    0
4    e  [8/10/2021, 9/27/2021, 10/3/2021, 11/10/2021, ...  ...        4    2
```